# Trouble importing security libraries in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to make use of the BCrypt library that spring provides. I've looked up many tutorials, but for some odd reason, almost none of them attempt to show what the build.gradle file should contain to access them. Currently, I have this:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-crypto', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
}
```

In my actual java file, I have this:

```
package project;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

However, I see these errors when I try to build:

```
error: cannot find symbol import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration;
                                                     ^
symbol:   class configuration
location: package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web

error: package org.springframework.security.crypto does not exist 
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password;

error: cannot find symbol public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
                                     ^
symbol: class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

error: cannot find symbol
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
           ^
symbol:   class PasswordEncoder
location: class SecurityConfig
```

Which dependencies am I missing and how can I find them when the tutorials leave them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to be trying to import *the package itself* instead of *a class from inside the package*.

Instead of

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration;
```

you should have

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
```

Note that using an IDE will make this *much* easier, as it will autocomplete the class names for you and automatically add the appropriate import.

All of this said, the best way to find a dependency for a class you can't seem to find is to search [the Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/). You can search by simple class name or use `fc:` to [search by full class name](https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter).